# How to use the Python packaging library with a custom regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pep

I'm trying to build and tag artifacts, the environment name gets appended at the end of the release, e.g.: `1.0.0-stg` or `1.0.0-sndbx`, none of them are PEP-440 compliance, raising the following error message:

```
raise InvalidVersion(f"Invalid version: '{version}'")
packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '1.0.0-stg'
```

Using the [packaging](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/) library I know I can access the regex by doing:

```
from packaging import version
version.VERSION_PATTERN
```

However, my question is how can I customize the regex rule also to support other environments?

Comment: What version pattern are you using?

Comment: I'm using major.minor.patch-environment, where environment could be dev, stg, sndbx and prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original value of the `version.VERSION_PATTERN` has used regex groups to separate the types of the version. And if you see the pattern, it defines three types of releases: **pre-release**, **post-release**, and **dev release**.

```
v?
(?:
    (?:(?P<epoch>[0-9]+)!)?                           # epoch
    (?P<release>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)                  # release segment
    (?P<pre>                                          # pre-release
        [-_\.]?
        (?P<pre_l>(a|b|c|rc|alpha|beta|pre|preview))
        [-_\.]?
        (?P<pre_n>[0-9]+)?
    )?
    (?P<post>                                         # post release
        (?:-(?P<post_n1>[0-9]+))
        |
        (?:
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<post_l>post|rev|r)
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<post_n2>[0-9]+)?
        )
    )?
    (?P<dev>                                          # dev release
        [-_\.]?
        (?P<dev_l>dev)
        [-_\.]?
        (?P<dev_n>[0-9]+)?
    )?
)
(?:\+(?P<local>[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_\.][a-z0-9]+)*))?       # local version
```

So you should add the `stg` and `sndbx` environment names next to the particular group name. In case those values do not present in the list, the version will always be counted as a local version and not a release version.

If those are **pre-releases**, you should add them to the `pre_l` group.

```
(?P<pre_l>(a|b|c|rc|alpha|beta|pre|preview|stg|sndbx))
```

In case those are **post-release** environments, the `post_l` should be changed, becoming:

```
(?P<post_l>post|rev|r|stg|sndbx)
```

And if those are **dev release** environments, the `dev_l` group should be updated in the same way.

```
(?P<dev_l>dev|stg|sndbx)
```

Once you have decided on the type of release and set values to the particular groups, you can override the `version.VERSION_PATTERN` and see the result.

```py
from packaging import version

version.VERSION_PATTERN = r"""
    v?
    (?:
        (?:(?P<epoch>[0-9]+)!)?                           # epoch
        (?P<release>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)                  # release segment
        (?P<pre>                                          # pre-release
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<pre_l>(a|b|c|rc|alpha|beta|pre|preview))
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<pre_n>[0-9]+)?
        )?
        (?P<post>                                         # post release
            (?:-(?P<post_n1>[0-9]+))
            |
            (?:
                [-_\.]?
                (?P<post_l>post|rev|r)
                [-_\.]?
                (?P<post_n2>[0-9]+)?
            )
        )?
        (?P<dev>                                          # dev release
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<dev_l>dev|stg|sndbx)
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<dev_n>[0-9]+)?
        )?
    )
    (?:\+(?P<local>[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_\.][a-z0-9]+)*))?       # local version
"""
```

**NOTE:** It is not required to add both identifiers of environments into one group. So one of them can be added to another group.

Comment: thank you, this has resolved the issue, didn't know we could overwrite the value of `VERSION_PATTERN`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the PEP-440 guidelines are built into this package quite tightly. The simpler solution may be to use Local Version Identifiers, which are more customizable, by adding `+someId` to the end of your versions. So you could have `1.0.0+stg`

https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers